# How to make this section full height of the screen? Whatever we do it leaves white space on the bottom

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

We are trying to make the content full height of the screen but whatever we do it shows white space on the bottom of the screen. How can be it fixed?

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background: #FF512F;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  padding-top: 5%;
  /* New code */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  height: 150%;
}

.emp-profile {
  padding: 10%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px
}
```

```html
<section *ngIf="user" (onlineUsers)="online($event)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="emp-profile justify-content-center">
      ... ...
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I can't use body tag because this is an angular separate component and starts with the section.

How can I make that section full height of the screen? We are using Bootstrap 4 with Angular 6

Answer (score 0):

There is a negative margin on the section. That moves the entire section up 150px. Also don't define height twice in the CSS. Whatever the negative margin is, it must be added back to the height...

```
section {
    height: calc(100vh + 80px);
    background-size: cover;
    background: #FF512F; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/BdVBClITv0

Comment: It's again the same.

Answer (score -1):

added `100vh` and removed `margin` and `padding` `section`

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background: #FF512F;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476);
  /* New code */
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.emp-profile {
  padding: 10%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<section *ngIf="user" (onlineUsers)="online($event)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="emp-profile justify-content-center">
      ... ...
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's still the same

Comment: you mean to say the white space `emp-profile`. can you please show a screenshot.

Comment: No, as far as the section has a gradiend background that gradient background doesn't cover the whole screen and there is a white space on the bottom.

Comment: can you show where there is white space at the bottom. thanks